# glLoadMatrix() replacement

Tags: opengl, matrix, deprecated

After porting my game to newer OpenGL versions (3.2+), I noticed that `glLoadMatrix()` and `glMultMatrix()` were removed. Is there a replacement for them? I don't want to use any libs since I have my own matrix stack.

Comment: If you don't want to use libraries, you're gonna have to implement functions like `glMultMatrix` yourself. You can pass your matrix to your shader using `glUniformMatrix4fv`.

Comment: I'm already using glUniformMat4fv. But screen is empty without glLoadMatrix.

Comment: @user3147635: Are you using the deprecated fixed-function compatibility uniforms (`gl_ModelViewMatrix` et al) in your shaders?

Comment: No, I replaced all deprecated stuff. The problem is only one: screen is blank without glLoadMatrix.

Comment: Time for a SSCCE then.

Comment: The idea is to roll your own replacement.

Comment: That's what I am asking :(

Comment: Well, seems like I got blank screen because OS X ( 3.2 core ) doesnt want to render anything. Just tested on windows without glLoadMatrix and it works perfectly. DAMN.

Comment: This could well mean that you're still using something that is not compatible with the core profile. Not using VAOs for vertex handling is one of the most common issues when this happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The old GL matrix stack is removed from modern OpenGL, meaning that all the matrix related functions are gone, including `glPushMatrix`, `glPopMatrix`, `glLoadMatrix`, etc. Those functions served the purpose of allowing the application to send transform data to the fixed-function pipeline.

Since now you write your own pipeline with programable shaders, it is going to be entirely up to you how you are going to handle passing the transformation matrices to the shaders. The usual approach is by using [uniform variables](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) or [uniform buffers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object).

So in your shaders you can declare as many matrices as is needed by the application, with:

```
uniform mat4 u_mvpMatrix;    // there are also mat3 and mat2
uniform mat4 u_modelMatrix;
...
```

And set/update them with [`glUniformMatrix*()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml).

If you don't have a good matrix library yet, you will certainly need one, because matrix multiplication and any other operation now has to be done by the application as well. A very good option is [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html).